# Mongoose save callback is not fired

Tags: node.js

bear.js:

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var BearSchema   = new Schema({
    name: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Bear', BearSchema);
```

server.js:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://myuser:mypass@ds037175.mongolab.com:27175/words');

var Bear = require('./app/models/bear.js');
// ROUTES FOR OUR API
// =============================================================================
var router = express.Router();              // get an instance of the express Router

router.use(function(req,res,next) {
    //do logging
    console.log('Smth is happening');
    next();
});

router.route('/bears')

    // create a bear (accessed at POST http://localhost:8080/api/bears)
    .post(function(req, res) {
        var bear = new Bear();      // create a new instance of the Bear model
        bear.name = req.body.name;  // set the bears name (comes from the request)

        // save the bear and check for errors
        bear.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
              }
            res.json({ message: 'Bear created!' });
        });

    });
```

Im trying to connect with Postman, it seems like the **save** callback is not fired, there is no respond  - "Could not get any response" after a while.

(Ive tried to connect to my mongo  DB via terminal and succeeded ).
Im new to node.js so be soft with me. not sure how to debug or why this is happening.

Comment: Try adding a callback to your `mongoose.connect` call to see if you're successfully connecting or not.

Comment: Thanks, console.log(Bear.connection.readyState); logs me error of undefined, i have no clue how to debug it further though

Comment: Your comment doesn't appear to be related to my suggestion on how to debug this. :) Add a `function(err, db) { if (err) { ...} }` parameter to your `mongoose.connect` call to see if there was an error in connecting.